# DynamoDbSecondaryPartitionKey annotation in AWS SDK v2 ignored in Kotlin

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, amazon-dynamodb, spring-webflux

Using Spring Boot, DynamoDbEnhancedAsyncClient from the v2 AWS Java SDK, and DynamoDB running using testcontainers and localstack, I fail to get a table from the client with a secondary index as specified in my Dynamo DB bean data class. Everything written in Kotlin.

Bean:

```
@DynamoDbBean
data class MyEntity (
    @get:DynamoDbPartitionKey
    @get:DynamoDbAttribute("entityId")
    var entityId: String = "",

    @get:DynamoDbAttribute("customerId")
    @get:DynamoDbSecondaryPartitionKey(indexNames = ["CustomerIdIndex"])
    val customerId: String = "",

    @get:DynamoDbSecondarySortKey(indexNames = ["CustomerIdIndex"])
    @get:DynamoDbAttribute("createdAt")
    val createdAt: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()
) {
    companion object {
        val tableName: String = "my-entity"
}
```

Query implementation:

```
@Repository
class MyEntityRepository(client: DynamoDbEnhancedAsyncClient) {
    companion object {
        private val tableSchema = TableSchema.fromBean(MyEntity::class.java)
        private val tableName = MyEntity::class.java.simpleName
    }

    private val table = client.table(tableName, tableSchema)

    override suspend fun findByCustomerId(customerId: String): Flow<MyEntity> {
        val conditional: QueryConditional = QueryConditional.keyEqualTo(
            Key.builder()
                .partitionValue(customerId)
                .build()
        )

        val request = QueryEnhancedRequest.builder()
            .queryConditional(conditional)
            .scanIndexForward(false)
            .build()

        val queryPublisher: SdkPublisher<Page<PaymentMethod>> = table
            .index("CustomerIdIndex")
            .query(request)
    }
}
```

Querying on the primary partition key works. However, when above code tries to query on the GSI, I get the error message:

> Attempt to execute an operation that requires a secondary index without defining the index attributes in the table metadata. Index name: CustomerIdIndex
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempt to execute an operation that requires a secondary index without defining the index attributes in the table metadata. Index name: CustomerIdIndex
>
> at software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.mapper.StaticTableMetadata.getIndex(StaticTableMetadata.java:150)

If I debug the code, looking at the table variable, I can indeed see that the DynamoDB client has not picked up the secondary index, as shown here:

[image: Debugger output for the DynamoDB Table]

So it seems to me that the annotations in the bean data class for the secondary index is not picked up. I'm struggling with finding the reason for that.

Appreciate all input, thank you.